# UFW allow outbound from ip address, deny from others

Tags: ufw

I am trying to allow outbound connections from a specific IP address and deny outbound from all other ip addreses on port 80, but can't seem to crack it:

These are the commands:

```
ufw deny out 80
ufw allow out from xxx.xx.xx.xx
```

However it is not allowing outbound connections to port 80 from xx.xx.xx.xx:

```
80                         DENY OUT    Anywhere (out)
Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   xxx.xx.xx.xx (out)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3):

The following would prevent outgoing traffic on port 80 but to the ip xxx.xx.xx.xx

1. change the default outgoing open in ufw

   ```
   ufw deny out 80
   ```
2. allow outgoing to the specific ip:

   ```
   ufw allow out to xxx.xx.xx.xx port 80
   ```